# pandas sort dataframe by column that includes numbers and letters

Tags: python, pandas

I need to sort a dataframe by one column, which includes a combination of numbers and letters.

```
df = [{"user": "seth",
       "name": "1"},
     {"user" : "chris",
       "name": "10A"},
     {"user" : "aaron",
       "name": "4B"},
     {"user" : "dan",
       "name": "10B"}]
```

My code:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(by=['name'])
```

This gets me:

```
df1 = [{"user": "seth",
       "name": "1"},
     {"user" : "chris",
       "name": "10A"},
     {"user" : "dan",
       "name": "10B"},
     {"user" : "aaron",
       "name": "4B"}]
```

I want:

```
df1 =    [{"user": "seth",
           "name": "1"},
         {"user" : "aaron",
           "name": "4B"},
         {"user" : "chris",
           "name": "10A"},
         {"user" : "dan",
           "name": "10B"}]
```

I had a different question that was flagged as a similar question, and their code:

```
   df.reindex(index=natsorted(df.name))
```

It returns a sorted dataframe, but all values have been replaced by NaNs.

```
  df.iloc(natsorted(df.name))
```

It raises an error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: use `.iloc[natsorted(...)` instead of `reindex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To slightly correct Quang's comment, this works fine

```
import natsort

df1.iloc[natsort.index_humansorted(df1.name)]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Update using pandas 1.1.0+ [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#sorting-with-keys) now has key parameter:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"user": "seth",
       "name": "1"},
     {"user" : "chris",
       "name": "10A"},
     {"user" : "aaron",
       "name": "4B"},
     {"user" : "dan",
       "name": "10B"}])

df.sort_values('name', key=lambda x: x.str.extract('(\d+)').squeeze().astype(int))
```

Output:

```
    user name
0   seth    1
2  aaron   4B
1  chris  10A
3    dan  10B
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the column you're sorting by has some values that do not contain numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can now also do (with pandas >= 1.1.0):

```
import natsort

sorted_df = df1.sort_values("name", key=natsort.natsort_keygen())
```

Comment: Nice! This also supports sorting by multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a regular expression and extract the numbers + letters, sort them and assign as a categorical column.

```
s = df["name"].str.extract("(\d+)?(\w|)")
s[0]= s[0].astype(int)

print(s)

   0  1
0   1   
1  10  A
2   4  B
3  10  B



df['name'] = pd.Categorical(df['name'],s.sort_values([0,1]).astype(str).agg(''.join,axis=1))


print(df.sort_values('name')

   user name
0   seth    1
2  aaron   4B
1  chris  10A
3    dan  10B
```